# How do I make the "for" loop cycle through all lines of a text file in python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file "abc.txt" containing several lines of text. I am trying to count and list the frequency of appearance of each letter of the alphabet, a till z, in the txt file.

In the code below, after checking for the letter 'a' correctly, it returns 0 as count for the rest of the alphabets from 'b' onwards. Once the 'for' loop is executed for the letter 'a', for the subsequent letters, how I make it loop back to the beginning of the text again?

```
with open(r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\abc.txt","r") as x:
    for j in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        n = 0
        for i in x:
            y = i.count(j)
            n += y
        print(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because once you've read the entire file, the "pointer" or "cursor" is now at the end of the file, there are no more lines to read, and thus the rest of the checks end with 0.

To fix this move the cursor back to the top of the file after each loop of the outer for loop using the [`seek()`](https://code-maven.com/python-seek) function:

```
import os

with open(r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\abc.txt","r") as x:
    for j in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        n = 0
        for i in x:
            y = i.count(j)
            n += y
        print(n)
        x.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
```

EDIT:

It is probably worth making everyline lowercase before counting:

```
y = i.lower().count(j)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I am still fairly new to Python and hadn't come across the 'seek' function yet. I will look it up.

Comment: If this helpled, set this answer as accepted, thanks! Also, I added a note about making the lines lowercase to prevent letters from being missed if they are uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Your file handle `x` is an exhausted iterator after the iteration. You would have to reset it to the beginning of the file after each counting loop. But it is way more efficient to count all letters in one iteration:

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter()
with open(r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\abc.txt","r") as x:
    for i in x:
        cnt.update(i)
for j in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    print(cnt[j])
```

Comment: and the uppercases?

Comment: What about them? The OP does not mention any upper case letters, and claims their code works for `"a"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
count = {}
with open(r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\abc.txt","r") as x:
    srt = x.read()
    for i in srt:
        if i not in count:
            count[i] = srt.count(i)
            srt.replace(i,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

After iterating over the file the first time with the `for i in x` loop, the file is exhausted.  All the other `for i in x` loops will not run at all.

Instead of iterating over the file directly, load the file contents into a variable which can be examined repeatedly.

Also, it looks like you don't actually need to scan the file line-by-line; you can examine the entire file contents in one step.

Try this code:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\abc.txt","r") as x:
    text = x.read()

for letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    frequency = text.count(letter)
    print(frequency)
```

Comment: and the uppercases? what about them?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese The original code did not address uppercase letters, so my answer did not either.

Comment: @JohnGordon, "load the file contents into a variable which can be examined repeatedly." I understand this simplifies my code, but is this recommended if the text file is a huge document? In that case, is it more memory intensive to dump everything into a variable before checking or to read the file directly? Sorry, if this question sounds silly, I don't have formal programming background and am teaching myself now.

Comment: If it's a huge document, then the best solution is probably to reorganize your code so that the file iteration is the outermost loop and is thus done only once, and the alphabet letter iteration is an inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` for this.

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase


c = Counter()
letters = set(ascii_lowercase)
with open(r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\abc.txt","r") as f:
    c.update(letter for line in f for letter in line if letter in letters)
```

You don't need to scan the entire file for each letter.

Comment: This will count only one occurrence of each letter per line!

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks; I forgot to pay attention to which string I converted to a `set` to make use of `intersection`.

Comment: This still will discard duplicates. You should do just: `c.update(le for line in f for le in line if le in letters)`. Iterating any result of a set operation will drop the dupes =)

Comment: :facepalm: Yeah, that's what I had originally (I think).